# Android How to use use. Recycle View

Tags: java

I am new to android I want use recycle view in my app can someone briefly explain my the basic concept

Comment: What is itemView?

Comment: ItemView is the every row of the listView which has author, title,isbn and category

Answer (score 0):

Implement your BookItemView which is the ViewHolder class with View.OnClickListener like this:

```
 implements View.OnClickListener
```

And then call the implemented function of 
     OnClick()

Comment: I did it above, or give more explanations

Comment: Did you made this changes and checked? Also, what is itemview in here in your code?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should write the clickListener under RecyclerViewApter.onBindViewHolder

```
holder.view.setOnClickLister
```

like that if you click the item from recyclerView it will work